# SQL code to sum duplicate rows and also retain the duplicate rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to write a sql query

```
A        1    
B        1    
C        1    
A        1    
A        1    
B        1    
B        1    
C        1    
B        1
```

to make it look like

```
A      3
B      4
C      2
A      3
A      3
B      4
B      4
C      2
B      4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT field1, SUM(field2) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) as total
FROM table1
```

More info about window/analytic functions in Oracle :  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm

Comment: Im doing this on Oracle ...getting an error which says "invalid number" :(

Comment: What is type of `field2` ?

Comment: Got it !! Thanks a lot!!